# What is "o-matic"?

Tags: meaning, internet, catch-phrases, suffixes

I found "o-matic" in my dashboard of wordpress.com. There is "Read-o-Matic". And there are some news from staff. What does it mean? I feel it's "recommended to read", isn't it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the phrase 'Quote-O-Matic' mean?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6613/what-does-the-phrase-quote-o-matic-mean)

Comment: The close reason is the majority vote, but as you can see it is wrong, since we have a perfectly happy version of this question already. (And I think it's interesting.)

Answer (score 12):

This term comes from a number of American mechanical devices, and "omatic" is short for "automatic."

The so-called "Veg-o-matic" was an automatic *vegetable* slicer.

"Mince-o-matic" was an automatic meat *mincer*.

And "read-o-matic" would be an automatic *reader* (machine).

Answer (score 2):

Does anyone know of the first use of this?

It seems a 1950s term, the only example I can find is Ford's first automatic transmission the "cruise-o-matic" in 1958.

Comment: Goes back to the 1920s judging by ngrams.  Earliest thing I can find is the Williams Oil-O-Matic.  That actually sounds like *automatic* too. http://www.adclassix.com/images/25williamsoilfurnace.jpg

Comment: @z7sg - Couldn't get ngrams to work with the hyphen. Do you need a special syntax?

Comment: No I just searched for Matic rather than matic, as that excludes a lot of OCR hyphenation errors.

Comment: @Theta30  - yes but the question was already correctly answered, I was just trying to broaden it a little, Possibly should have been a comment to Tom's answer

Comment: Yeah, seems to have popped up in the 20s, probably as electricity started to get widespread and automatic machines starting doing a lot of work, then died off until the 50s with the Space Age and all that and culture fixating on the future and science fiction and what not, where in popular culture just about everything futuristic was a cliche-o-matic.

Comment: Nice bit of history. Upvoted.

Comment: @z7sgѪ Oil-O-Matic Heating Corporation was founded by Walter W. Williams in 1918. The earliest Oil-O-Matic text I can find is from two 1920 motoring magazines: "Oil-O-Matic oil cups are designed to operate only when the car is in operation" ... "using the Oil-O-Matic system of lubrication such part as the steering spindles, steering connections, ...", though it's not 100% clear if these are at all related to the Williams oil furnace. Also Butler Oilomatic windmills, subject of trademark litigation from Williams in the late 20s. Twinomatic Machine & Tool Co. has been around since at least 1918.